# Styles not getting Applied in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was making my custom bottom Navbar for which I am unable to Apply styles on my `View` component

This is what I am importing

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

And then in return of render, I am calling it like this (`this.something` are icons here)

```
  <View styles={headerContainer1}> 
            <Text> {this.News}</Text>
            <Text>{this.home}</Text>
            <Text> {this.Exchange}</Text>
            <Text> {this.about}</Text>
            </View>
```

Here my Header container looks/and is coming from here

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerContainer1 : {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "row",
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: "red",
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 0
    }
  })

  const { 
    headerContainer1
  } = styles;
```

Here, I have done two things. `flexDirection: "row",`and `backgroundColor: "red"` but unfortunately I can't see any of the changes being Applied.

**[Question:]** What am I missing or doing wrong? I am attaching the image below for reference

[image]

Comment: try `export default styles` in the style file. And `import styles from 'style file path'`, in the view, do `<View style={styles.headerContainer1}>...`. Also, the prop for view should be singular, so `style=`, not `styles=`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First thing in your view you have `styles` where it should be `style`. A quick questions, why are you setting a const to the style sheet?  Perhaps try bypassing the const and use:

```
  <View style={styles.headerContainer1}> 
        <Text> {this.News}</Text>
        <Text>{this.home}</Text>
        <Text> {this.Exchange}</Text>
        <Text> {this.about}</Text>
        </View>
```

Or perhaps just fix the view to change `styles` to `style`

```
  <View style={headerContainer1}> 
        <Text> {this.News}</Text>
        <Text>{this.home}</Text>
        <Text> {this.Exchange}</Text>
        <Text> {this.about}</Text>
        </View>
```

I'm not sure why you would do it like this, but I'm sure you have your reasons :>

Comment: That (s) was causing the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I had styles and not style. Simple answer that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your Stylesheet like this:

```
        <View style={styles.headerContainer1}> 
          <Text> {this.News}</Text>
          <Text>{this.home}</Text>
          <Text> {this.Exchange}</Text>
          <Text> {this.about}</Text>
        </View>
```

You just need to reference the Stylesheet, you wouldn't need the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but that isn't working as well. 
Also, For some reason I find second approach sort of clean (just personal preference here)

Comment: Can you post the full component?

Comment: Thanks a lot JRK. There was a stupid *s* I added in styles which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style={styles.name} in your desire components